# How do I play animation exactly N times?

Tags: python, animation

I need something like a python script to control exactly how many times I playback the animation in blender. I need to test simulated cloth, so I also want to clear simulation cache after every cycle. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The value you need to change in script:
**number_of_time_you_want_loop = 3

frame_start = 1

frame_end = 60**

```
# blender 2.93.3
# choice your current frame first
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

@persistent
def run_after_frame_change(dummy):
    #print("frame_changed")
    if bpy.context.scene.frame_current > frame_end:
        bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.remove(run_after_frame_change)
        bpy.ops.screen.animation_cancel()
        loop()

def loop():
    global n
    n += 1
    if n == number_of_time_you_want_loop:
        print("done")
        return

    bpy.context.scene.frame_current = frame_start
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(run_after_frame_change)
    bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()

n = 0
number_of_time_you_want_loop = 3
frame_start, frame_end = 1, 60
bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(run_after_frame_change)
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how would I clear simulation cache? I would also want to measure time/average fps of the animation as well as cpu/memory usage.

Comment: bpy.ops.ptcache.free_bake_all()    ➤ Delete all baked caches of all objects in the current scene

Comment: Thank you very much